# How to override widget deleting function?

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I add my own functionality to the method which is responsible for deleting widget ( when I drag and drop it on the recycle icon ).
I need to be able to add some additional implementation.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but youo can use this ...

```
@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        //You code here
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Comment: as far as I understand this callback is called, when all widgets are deleted.

Comment: (ref http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) Called in response to the ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED broadcast when one or more AppWidget instances have been deleted. Override this method to implement your own AppWidget functionality.
You can also look at onDisabled(Context context)if you have only 1 instance for widget

Comment: by the way, do you know how to determine current widget size in runtime?

Comment: what is max target sdk you are using in your app

Comment: Max is not specified. Min is 15.

Comment: guess that is not possible since i have searched AppWidget api I have not been able to find out ways to interact with Widgets not easy..
eg. you do not have any getters for wodget most of things are to be done before time.:(